# how to get the css code work for all the browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have written code in css in Eclipse IDE(mars1).

My code is working perfectly in Internet Explorer, but it is not working in Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge.

I mean the content is being displayed but the background-images and background colors I have used are not displaying in the Chrome browser, why is it so happening, what is the reason , how to rectify the error?

I am using `background-image`.

Example:

```
background-image:url("C:\project\images\background.jpg");
```

this is my code 
       this sis code

```
 body { 
  background:url("C:/COMPUTER/E drive/My Externalp,f.jgg");
 margin-left:10px;
color:#000000;
font-family:serif;
font-size: medium;
font-style:normal;
}
```

what should i do to work in chrome plaese explain in detail why is it working in chrome and not working in chrome 
i am using tomcat 7.0 server

Comment: Me too. But really - Install [http server](https://httpd.apache.org/) and start doing it right. And BTW, I.E browser is a standard for NOTHING AT ALL

Comment: But not to be a jerk... your files are housed on your local hard drive.  Using fully qualified paths like this (C:\) is generally not recommended... you should use relative paths like '../images/background.jpg' assuming your HTML is in in projects and your CSS is in a folder like 'style'.  The issue you're having is that local paths have a special path identifier for other browsers... which you just avoid by use of relative paths.

Comment: I guess that was an answer... and I have made it this.

Comment: as well as they say, perhavs your style file, jquery, boostrap or any other external file that you use are also referenced in the head of your code with the same type of path (full path), so is a good practice to use all the time relative paths for references this files, try to check tutorials and books, everyone of us began with zero knowlegde of how to code, so good luck

Comment: @EmmanuelLópez I disagree, when with a live server *absolute* paths are the way it should be done, a path beginning with `/`. relative paths are always dependent on two factors (where the page is based as well as where the resource is based) rather than just the location of the resource.

Comment: The point is that figuring out why this doesn't work in Chrome when using a fully qualified path won't be applicable to when the website/app is deployed to virtually any kind of live environment.  So it's not really worth figuring out.  You should be working in a development environment that is as close to the deployed env as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Your files are housed on your local hard drive. Using fully qualified paths like this (C:\projects) is generally not recommended...(and will break).

You should use relative paths like '../images/background.jpg' assuming your HTML is in in projects and your CSS is in a folder like 'style'. The issue you're having is that local paths have a special path identifier for other browsers... which you just avoid by use of relative paths.

Or, really, install some sort of HTTP server and really do it right.

Comment: i want reason why is it working in IE and not working in chrome

Comment: this sis code  <style type="text/css">

     body { 
      background:url("C:/COMPUTER/E drive/My Externalp,f.jgg");
     margin-left:10px;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:serif;
    font-size: medium;
    font-style:normal;
    }
  how should i modify to this to work in chrome

Comment: Because IE is stupid and allows all sorts of things that break specifications.  That's (one reason) why a very very small percentage of developers use it as a first-line browser.  The general consensus is that IE (and Edge) is better than it was... but it is still crap.

Answer (score 0):

I have an itch to qualify [Johns good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38150484/3536236) that when a website is on a hosting server, rather than on a local machine, that relative paths should be changed to being *absolute* paths from the root of the website, each path beginning with a `/`.

> ```
> For following examples website page is at C:\website\pages\index.html
> ```

Current local path:

```
C:\website\images\backing.jpg
```

Current *relative* path (as suggested quite correctly by John):

```
../images/backing.jpg
```

Current *absolute* path for when your website is live on a server:

```
/images/backing.jpg
```

The reason for this is that *relative* paths are dependant on two factors; for not only where the resource (the path to the item) is based, but also where the current page the request is coming from is based. Whereas with Absolute pathing, you don't care where the page is based, as long as the resource is reachable at the given address it will work.

Pages can be copy/pasted from `here/index.html` to `here/and/there/index.html` without any need to change any addresses and both will load all Absolutely referenced resources without fail. Relative resources will need to all be adjusted. For each folder.

---

As a small aside, I (vaguely) remember an issue that Chrome *will* load local drive content but the slashes would need to be swapped, so

```
<img src='C:\images\hello.jpg'>
```

would need to become

```
<img src='C:/images/hello.jpg'>
```

Comment: Nomenclature is still (to this day) out on whether or not the preceeding slash is an absolute path.  The general meaning of absolute path is a fully qualified URL, but it can be viewed both ways (I call it an absrel to my developers to avoid confusion).  That being said, I don't recommend them without a larger supporting framework.  If you're a designer and dealing with work files, you want to be able to view them without a server... so it really depends on your vocation as to whether or not it is the 'right' thing to choose absrel paths.

Comment: true, but if I reference resources with a preceeding slash then it doesn't matter where the referencing page is itself based, and as far as I can tell this is a universally accepted trait by browsers. Interesting comment, I would also use a `<base>` reference in the URL as well just to make sure. @JohnGreen